# C++ Initialize Pointer in Member Initialization List

Tags: c++, initialization

I am wondering if there is a way I can, in my class' constructors, initialize an array in the base initialization list.

Right now, I am initializing myChars (a char*) to an empty character array of size DEFAULT_SIZE:

```
    A::A() :
      mySize(0), maxSize(DEFAULT_SIZE)
    {
         myChars = new char[DEFAULT_SIZE];
    }
```

Is there any way to do this in the base initialization list? So that it would be simply:

```
     A::A() :
      mySize(0), maxSize(DEFAULT_SIZE), **myChars initialized here**
    {
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the complete class declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try?

```
 A::A() :
  mySize(0), maxSize(DEFAULT_SIZE), myChars(new char[DEFAULT_SIZE])
{}
```

However, it's *extremely* recommended to use `std::string`, `std::vector<char>`, or `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` instead, all of which manage memory without error.

Comment: Ok, I don't know why I thought it would be any different. Thank you.